# Arch modeling Python

Tags: r, python-2.7, volatility

I have been using Python to fit an ARCH model to monthly return series of Intel stock from 1989-2010.  I have used the ARCH library written by Kevin Shepphard.  Now, when cross checking with R, my coefficients of Volatilty model is slightly different than what R tells me it is.  I am wondering, why is there so many differences in results across packages?  Which language is correct then?  R's fGarch package or Kevin shepphards package?  The problem is the p values across the two languages are completely different.  I'm confused which language to use to get the correct results.  I have attached the link to my work below.  If you scroll down, you will be able to see my Python implementation where I'm trying to fit a arch(3) model and likewise Rs implementation.  If someone can please explain where the difference is coming from and which package to trust, I would highly appreciate it

Thanks

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/mrajancsr/96a19065794c8c0bd850

Comment: Btw, whoever reads this.  Arch library in Python is completely messed up compared to R.  Coefficients of the volatility model are completely misspecified and the resulting P values are wrong as well.  I contacted the author and still haven't gotten a response.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in 95ccc3e on August 6, 2015

https://github.com/bashtage/arch/commit/95ccc3e94d408d92c6d0d8635a62ff2a26243f45